# Evaluate $\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{n\log_2^2 n}\,dn$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Wolfram Alpha tells me that $\displaystyle\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{n\log_2^2 n} \, dn = \ln 2$.   Could anyone show me in small steps how to get this answer?

Comment: Set $u = \log_2 n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First notice that 
$$\log_2 x=\frac{\log x}{\log 2}$$
now we have

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x\log^2 x}=\int_0^\infty\frac{f'(x)dx}{f^2(x)}=-\frac{1}{f(x)}\Bigg|_2^\infty=\frac{1}{\log 2}$$
where $f(x)=\log x$.
 Combine the two result.

Comment: @Adobe thanks for the edit.

Comment: You're welcome! :-)