# In general, if there is a big | with a subscript and a subscript, what does it mean?

Tags: real-analysis

In general, if there is a big | with a subscript and a subscript, what does it mean?

Example: from this answer [Evaluate $\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{n\log_2^2 n}\,dn$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629391/evaluate-int-2-infty-frac1n-log-22n)

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x\log^2 x}=\int_0^\infty\frac{f'(x)dx}{f^2(x)}=-\frac{1}{f(x)}\Bigg|_2^\infty=\frac{1}{\log 2}$$

How do we go from step 3 to step 4 ?

Thank you.

Comment: Evaluate at the point indicated by the superscript, and in the point indicated by the subscript, take the difference: $$g(x)\Bigl\lvert_2^\infty = g(\infty) - g(2).$$ $$-\frac{1}{f(x)}\Bigl\lvert_2^\infty = \left(-\frac{1}{f(\infty)}\right) - \left(-\frac{1}{f(2)}\right) = \frac{1}{f(2)} - \frac{1}{f(\infty)}.$$

Comment: $f(x)|_a^b$ means $f(b)-f(a)$ or the limit $\lim_{x\to b} f(x)-\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$

Comment: And if we have $\int g(x)|_2^\infty dx$ I do $\int g(2) dx - \int g(\infty) dx$ ???

Comment: this notation is used as short notation of the evaluation of the integral where $f$ is the primitive of the integrand...$\int_a^b F(x)dx=f(x)|_a^b$

Comment: $\int d(x) dx|_2^\infty =\int_2^\infty d(x) dx$

Comment: take a look [here](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CF8QFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uakron.edu%2F~dpstory%2Ftutorial%2Fc1%2Fc1i_t1.pdf&ei=sxDLUr_rFeSt0QXT-4BQ&usg=AFQjCNGiE_18IFHLyCKHwUu8VFI6z1YpZg&sig2=ZvCsY1gfiuM6X6BEPJmufw&bvm=bv.58187178,d.d2k&cad=rja) pag. 65-66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\infty$ and $2$ make the integral **definite.** You are calculating the integral on the closed interval $[2,\space\infty]$ where $\infty$ is the upper bound and $2$ is the lower bound. How to deal with **definite integrals** is that you substitute the upper and lower bounds respectively into the remaining function and then subtract (the lower bound from the upper bound). So:
$$-\frac{1}{f(x)}\bigg|_2^{\infty} = -\frac{1}{f(\infty)}-\left(-\frac{1}{f(2)}\right)$$

From your comment, you wouldnt have "$\int g(x)\bigg|_2^{\infty}$" together, the "$\bigg|_2^{\infty}$" notation is **after you have integrated** $g(x)$ and will be substituting the lower and upper bounds..

$$\int_2^{\infty} g(x) dx=h(x)\bigg|_2^{\infty} = h(\infty)-h(2)$$

where $h(x)$ is the **integral** of $g(x)$.
You can read more [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Terminology_and_notation)

For example, $$\int_2^{10}6x^5=x^6\bigg|_2^{10}=10^6-2^6=...$$